# JSF - Triggering methods on submit

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I am using composite, tag or custom components in my new JSF 2.1 powered application.

I still often ignores the right (or at least recommended) way to proceed with this technology.

I would like my components to perform some action when the user is clicking on the "save" button. Practically, the save button is a Primefaces commandButton.

So, I am using button code such as:

```
<p:commandButton id="example" type="submit" value="Confirmer les modifications" process="targetComponent" update="<compoents to update list>">
    <f:param name="save" value="true>
</p:commandButton>
```

for the "save" button and in my components, I use the preRenderComponent to trigger an handleSubmit backing bean method :

```
<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{myBeautifulBean.handleSubmit}"/>
```

handleSumit looks like:

```
public void handleSubmit() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String saveMandats = JSFUtils.getRequestParameter("save");
    if(context.isPostback() && !context.isValidationFailed() && (saveMandats != null) && !saveMandats.isEmpty())
        confirmeModifsSelection();
}
```

This ***works***.

Reading stackoverflow and trying to follow @BalusC adviced, I am using omnifaces (1.2) and trying to use the postInvokeAction event, for reasons explained in [OmniFaces `InvokeActionEventListener` showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener).

So, I am changing my event tag to:

```
<f:event type="postInvokeAction" listener="#{myBeautifulBean.handleSubmit}"/>
```

...and myBeautifulBean.handleSubmit is never called.

I am, of course, having omnifaces as a dependency and other components (validators, etc.) just works. The InvokeActionListener is properly initialized (or seems so to me).

Should the postInvokeAction be registered at a specific time ? I noticed that in omnifaces examples, {pre|post}InvokeAction events are always declared as children in f:metadata tags.

I found lots of example where preRenderView events are declared outside of f:metadata, like: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/

By the way, if I am plain wrong proceeding this way, I will be glad to learn from your wisdom. But I want to avoid:

- to have chain calls of backing beans methods triggered by a p:commandButton action handler ;
- declaring every such action handler as a f:actionListener child of the commandButton.

I am looking for a more event oriented way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned and shown in the [`InvokeActionEventListener` showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener), this event works on `UIViewRoot`, `UIForm`, `UIInput` and `UICommand` only. So if you want a generic hook (on the view), then you'd need to put it on `UIViewRoot`. This needs to be done by placing it in `<f:metadata>`.

The `preRenderComponent` and `preRenderView` doesn't require a specific parent component, you can practically place it everywhere in the view, it's always be registered to the closest parent UI component. This does not make much sense for the `preInvokeAction`/`postInvokeAction` as not *every* kind of component participates in invoke action. Placing it in for example a `<h:panelGroup>` wouldn't have been very self-documentatory.

Comment: No, they must reside on the top-level view. But as far as I understand you, you'd like to use `postInvokeAction` in a composite component?

Comment: Composite, tag or custom (I use all kinds).

Comment: ok, I found a very simple workaround : I add the {pre|post}InvokeAction event to a h:inputHidden.