# Render head after listener methods of preRenderView & preRenderComponent inside body have executed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to set a dynamic page title to the page which is retrieved after preRenderView & preRenderComponent's listeners inside document body have been executed. But I find that title is rendered before those listeners were executed.

Is there any way I could delay the rendering of title tag until listeners have executed ?

Comment: don't look for a way to delay , just look for a hook that can be used after `preRenderXXX` , place `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
  if (data.status === "success") {alert('hello');}});` and see if its being invoked after your listeners...

Comment: Is this to be exeucted on a synchronous or an asynchronous request? PreRenderView should work fine, PreRenderComponent would only work when hooked on `UIViewRoot`.

Comment: @balusC :The document `<title>` inside `h:head` needs to be set on initial page request but after listeners have executed

Comment: @Daniel: This is not updated via ajax but needs to be done while initial page request only.

Comment: @user01 , how about using `RequestContext` ... `context.execute(someJsCode)` to update the title from managed bean ?

Comment: @Daniel: I know the JS way but it wont be SEO compatible..

Comment: @BalusC: please see my answer below (my workaround strategy) & leave your valuable feedback.

Comment: @Daniel: Found a workaround strategy, please let me know what you think of this.

Comment: @user01 not sure if that a proper way to use the `preRenderComponent` , but it works....

Comment: @Daniel: Do you mean f:event with `preRenderComponent`  should have been placed inside a proper parent JSF component instead of directly under `ui:define` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13268395/617373 , but I havent actually used preRenderComponent  myself too much so I can't advise on it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried following strategy as a workaround. I just move `f:event type="preRenderComponent"..` from inside `body` to `head` section & I get the desired behavior.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>

<ui:define name="titleOfPage">
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.method()}"/>
    #{bean.title}
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="bodyOfPage">
    ..
    ..
</ui:define>
```

master template:

```
<h:head>
    ... 
    <title><ui:insert name="titleOfPage"></ui:insert></title>
</h:head>
<h:body >
     <ui:insert name="bodyOfPage">Body of the pages goes here</ui:insert>
</h:body >
```

---

First listener method is invoked & then  `title` inside `head` is rendered.

Perhaps `PreRenderView` type could have been used directly without requiring to move the `f:event` tag to head but `PreRenderView` is triggered even on ajax requests which is not desired.